# can i get my current location with ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, gps, ionic3

This is the function to get distance locations with my current location

```
applyHaversine(locations) {

let usersLocation = {
  lat: 40.713744,
  lng: -74.009056
}; // before i have declared lat and lng.. and i want to this lat and lng can be filled by my current location 

locations.map((location) => {

  let placeLocation = {
    lat: location.latitude,
    lng: location.longitude
  };

  location.distance = this.getDistanceBetweenPoints(
    usersLocation,
    placeLocation,
    'miles'
  ).toFixed(2);
});

return locations;
}
```

Please the solutions for this lat and lng

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install and import `Geolocation` from [ionic native](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/geolocation/).

Once installed, import it like so:

```
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';

constructor(private geolocation: Geolocation) {
} // Add geolocation to your constructor



//Every time you enter the view, get the current location
//You need to call your logic after your lat and long have been set

ionViewWillEnter() {
   this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
      usersLocation.lat = resp.coords.latitude;
      usersLocation.lng = resp.coords.longitude;
      //Call to your logic HERE
   }).catch((error) => {
      alert(error);
   });
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54592356/ionic-3-geolocation-not-working-when-gps-is-disabled .  Please answer above question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in Ionic 3 you can use one of their native plugins called Geolocation.

This would be the code:

```
this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
  usersLocation.lat = resp.coords.latitude;
  usersLocation.lng = resp.coords.longitude;
}).catch((error) => {
 console.log('Error getting location', error);
});
```

Comment: where i am must place ?

Comment: You could place in the contructor of the page where you want the location. Were you are calculating all this distance calculations

Comment: i get this error : Cannot read property 'getCurrentPosition' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

@ChesterLaborde i am very confused where i must place that code...I've tried repeatedly still error

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { ConnectivityProvider } from '../connectivity/connectivity'
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';


@Injectable()
export class LocationsProvider {

  data: any;

  constructor(public http: Http, public geolocation: Geolocation) {

  }

load() {
if (this.data) {
  return Promise.resolve(this.data);
}

return new Promise(resolve => {

  this.http.get('assets/data/locations.json').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {

    this.data = this.applyHaversine(data.locations);

    this.data.sort((locationA, locationB) => {
      return locationA.distance - locationB.distance;
    });

    resolve(this.data);
  });

});

  }


  applyHaversine(locations) {

let usersLocation = {
  lat: 40.713744,
  lng: -74.009056
};


locations.map((location) => {

  let placeLocation = {
    lat: location.latitude,
    lng: location.longitude
  };

  location.distance = this.getDistanceBetweenPoints(
    usersLocation,
    placeLocation,
    'miles'
  ).toFixed(2);
});

return locations;
}

getDistanceBetweenPoints(start, end, units) {

let earthRadius = {
  miles: 3958.8,
  km: 6371
};

let R = earthRadius[units || 'miles'];
let lat1 = start.lat;
let lon1 = start.lng;
let lat2 = end.lat;
let lon2 = end.lng;

let dLat = this.toRad((lat2 - lat1));
let dLon = this.toRad((lon2 - lon1));
let a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
  Math.cos(this.toRad(lat1)) * Math.cos(this.toRad(lat2)) *
  Math.sin(dLon / 2) *
  Math.sin(dLon / 2);
let c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
let d = R * c;

return 
}

toRad(x) {
return x * Math.PI / 180;
  }
}
```

@ChesterLaborde Where i must place your code ?

Comment: Did you import it in your app.module as well?

Answer (score 0):

Is very simply with ionic, first install the [cordova gps wrapper](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/geolocation/) and after put the follow code in the page that you need access to position:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, IonicPage, ToastController, ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Geolocation ,GeolocationOptions ,Geoposition ,PositionError } from '@ionic-native/geolocation'; 


@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  private offlinemode: boolean = false;
  options : GeolocationOptions;
  currentPos : Geoposition;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
    public singletonProvider: SingletonauthProvider,
    public toastCtrl: ToastController, 
    private geolocation : Geolocation, 

  ) {

  }

  ionViewDidEnter(){
    this.viewCtrl.showBackButton(false);
    this.getUserPosition(); 
  }  

  getUserPosition(){
    this.options = {
        enableHighAccuracy : true
    };

    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.options).then((pos : Geoposition) => {

        this.currentPos = pos;      
        console.log(pos); // here is your current pos
       

    },(err : PositionError)=>{
        console.log("error : " + err.message);
        this.message("Could not detect your position");

    });
}
```